# haskell -- any way to generate "deriving" instances for roughly-tuple-isomorphic data types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, deriving

Suppose I have a data type like

```
data D a = D a a a
```

and a typeclass

```
class C c ...
instance (C c1, C c2) => C (c1, c2)
```

Then, I want to be able to write

```
data D a = D a a a deriving C
```

and have that generate an instance,

```
instance C ((a, a), a) => C (D a)
```

by using the modulo-lazy-evaluation isomorphism,

```
D a ~ ((a, a), a)
```

*Note*. Using a newtype and `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` will not work if, for example, one has `data D m = D (m Integer) (m Integer)`.

*Note 2*. This question has relevance for Haskell expressiveness in general -- languages like Python have something called named tuples, which can be used anywhere tuples are used; this question shows where/how I don't know how to emulate the same thing in Haskell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this relatively cleanly and efficiently using GHC 7.4's [generic programming support](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/generic-programming.html). The [documentation for GHC.Generics](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Generics.html) may be helpful. Here's an example.

Consider the following example class and some sample instances:

```
class C a where
  -- | Double all numbers
  double :: a -> a

instance C Int where
  double i = 2 * i

instance (C a, C b) => C (a, b) where
  double (a, b) = (double a, double b)
```

We need some language pragmas and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}
module Example where

import GHC.Generics hiding(C, D)
```

We now give some "generic instances". The generic types all have a phantom parameter `x`, which makes the instance heads a little more complicated:

```
-- "Insert" a normal value into a generic value
instance C c => C (K1 i c x) where
  double (K1 c) = K1 (double c)

-- Ignore meta-information (constructor names, type names, field names)
instance C (f x) => C (M1 i c f x) where
  double (M1 f) = M1 (double f)

-- Tuple-like instance
instance (C (f x), C (g x)) => C ((f :*: g) x) where
  double (f :*: g) = double f :*: double g
```

We now redefine our class `C` to take advantage of `GC`

```
class C a where
  -- | Double all numbers
  double :: a -> a

  -- specify the default implementation for double
  default double :: (Generic a, C (Rep a ())) => a -> a
  double = to0 . double . from0

-- from, with a more specialised type, to avoid ambiguity
from0 :: Generic a => a -> Rep a ()
from0 = from

-- to, with a more specialised type, to avoid ambiguity
to0 :: Generic a => Rep a () -> a
to0 = to
```

Now we can define some instances very easily:

```
data D a = D a a a deriving Generic
instance C a => C (D a)

data D2 m = D2 (m Int) (m Int) deriving Generic
instance C (D2 D)
```

Comment: Updated my answer to avoid the helper class; see http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/97079