# Can I use DerivingVia to derive instances for data types isomorphic to tuples

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

Given the following data type

```hs
data Both a b = Both { left :: a, right :: b }
```

I can write instances for Applicative etc. like so (omitting Functor here as we can use `DeriveFunctor`):

```hs
instance Monoid a => Applicative (Both a) where
    pure x = Both mempty x
    Both u f <*> Both v x = Both (u <> v) (f x)
```

Since `Both` is isomorphic to `(a,b)`, I'm wondering whether I can use `DerivingVia` to derive the instance:

```hs
data Both a b = ... deriving Applicative via ((,) a)
```

which results in error messages like:

```
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘(a, a1)’
                               with that of ‘Both a a1’
        arising from the coercion of the method ‘pure’
          from type ‘forall a1. a1 -> (a, a1)’
            to type ‘forall a1. a1 -> Both a a1’
    • When deriving the instance for (Applicative (Both a))
```

which I interpret as "the compiler doesn't know how to turn `Both` into `(,)`". How do I tell the compiler to do that using *the obvious way*?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659919/haskell-any-way-to-generate-deriving-instances-for-roughly-tuple-isomorphic) and the answers, but I'm hoping for a solution that requires less boilerplate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68650832/5247502), and with the help of the `generic-data` package one can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DerivingStrategies, DerivingVia #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Generic.Data

data Both a b = Both {left :: a, right :: b}
  deriving stock (Generic1)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative) via Generically1 (Both a)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [DerivingVia paper](https://www.kosmikus.org/DerivingVia/deriving-via-paper.pdf) has a section on using `Generic` to derive arbitrary classes for things that are "isomorphic via `Generic`". See 4.3.

I feel like I've seen the approach adapted to a library on hackage, but I can't seem to find it now.

However, I'm not sure it would work for your case, as `(a, b)` and your type might not have the same `Generic` representation (your type has record fields).
"data type generic surgery" could also be useful in that case - https://github.com/Lysxia/generic-data-surgery#readme